# getting the MonoBrickFirmware.dll library ev3 Button value as hexadecimal in F#

Tags: f#

```
            let buts: ButtonEvents = new ButtonEvents()

            let event =
                match buts with
                    | add_UpPressed     ->
                        Vehicle(pen, pen).Forward(SPEED)
                    | add_DownPressed   ->
                        Vehicle(pen, pen).Backward(SPEED)
                    | UpReleased    ->
                        Vehicle(pen, pen).Off()
                    | DownReleased  ->
                        Vehicle(pen, pen).Off()
                    | RightPressed  ->
                        Vehicle(assembly, assembly).Forward(SPEED)
                    | LeftPressed   ->
                        Vehicle(assembly, assembly).Backward(SPEED)
                    | RightReleased ->
                        Vehicle(assembly, assembly).Off()
                    | LeftReleased  ->
                        Vehicle(assembly, assembly).Off()
```

This is my code in F# and I'm using MonoBrickFirmware.dll library. In order to get the value of Button, I'm trying to define "buts".

But it doesn't work and still I couldn't manage to get the value of Button as hexadecimal or in another type.

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't work.  It doesn't compile, the match behaves weirdly - be more specific

Comment: Actually the problem is, I couldn't find the right method and class to get the value of Brick Button. Also it doesn't compile. I want to get the value as hexadecimal or in another variable type (whether it is upPress, downPress, upRelease, downRelease etc.), and match it with pattern matching John Palmer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The button events work in the following way in F# (you can just copy the code into Program.fs file in a newly created F# Console application):

```
module MyEV3FSharpExperiment

open MonoBrickFirmware.UserInput
open MonoBrickFirmware.Display
open System.Threading


// The main function that is called when the EXE is run on MonoBrick.
[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    let terminateProgram = new ManualResetEvent(false)
    let touchSensor = EV3TouchSensor(SensorPort.In1)
    // Initialize the button event
    let buts = new ButtonEvents ()
    // Add a handler function to the up button pressed event.
    buts.add_UpPressed((fun  () -> 
        LcdConsole.WriteLine("Sensor value:" + touchSensor.ReadAsString())
        () // The function is expeced to return a unit.
    ))
    // Add a handler for the event of the Escape button being pressed.
    buts.add_EscapePressed (fun () ->
        let _ =terminateProgram.Set()
        () // The function is expeced to return a unit.
    )

    // Add more event handlers here

    // Wait for the escape button to be pressed to quit. Program
    // execution will block at the following line until terminate event is set.
    let _ = terminateProgram.WaitOne()
    0 // The return value of the main method.
```

Please note that it is worth compiling the code with `--standalone` compiler switch. In Visual Studio 2013 you can set it in project properties (right click on project in Solution explorer -> Properties), then select "Build" from left and write `--standalone`into the `other flags` field. When you go to the "Application" tab in project settings, select the target runtime to be  "F# 3.0 (FSharp.Core 4.3.0.0)" and framework to be ".Net Framework 4.0", and Output type to be "Console Application".